# Christian kids cassette from the 90s

Tags: christian-living, music

I grew up in the 90s and when I would go to bed, my mom would put on these cassette tapes to listen to. Some of them were from the Psalty series, but there was this one I’ve been trying to find. I don’t think it’s a Psalty, but from what I can remember, it was about these kids who witness to these scientists who believe in evolution and there was this chant that the scientists did that went something like “ape man ape man ooo evolution evolution must be true ape man ape man ooo”. I know it probably sounds weird, but that’s what I remember. Does anyone know what I’m talking about or does it sound familiar to anyone else?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.